# HashTable (array) optimisation

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, hashmap

i have made a hasharray program because of school work and i am running into trouble with it not beign fast enough. It should run the school test in 300 ms, while my time ranges from 320 - almost 900ms. I have tried a couple of things and the most viable one would be to implement a dynamic array, potentialy something like **hashArray. I have trouble doing so, so I'm asking either for general help in optimising my code, or how i could implement it using a dynamic double array.

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARR_SIZE 44

int hashArray[ARR_SIZE][ARR_SIZE];

int hashKey(int data) {              //i create a hash key here, must be smaller than array max size
    while (data > ARR_SIZE) {
        data %= ARR_SIZE;
    }
    return data;
}

// vrati 1 ak 's' je podmnozina 't', inak vrati 0.
int is_subset(int s[], int ns, int t[], int nt) {
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nt; i++) {         //here i load numbers from the first array i get from input (the main set)
        if (hashArray[hashKey(t[i])] != NULL) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ARR_SIZE; j++) {
                if (hashArray[hashKey(t[i])][j] == NULL) {
                    hashArray[hashKey(t[i])][j] = t[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ns; i++) {         //and here i am comparing elemnts based on hashKey, if this array is a potential subset array of the previous one
        for (j = 0; j < ARR_SIZE; j++) {
            if (hashArray[hashKey(s[i])][j] == s[i]) 
                break;
            if (hashArray[hashKey(s[i])][j+1] != NULL)
                continue;
            else {
                memset(hashArray, 0, sizeof(hashArray));
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    memset(hashArray, 0, sizeof(hashArray));
    return 1;
}

// showcase test
int main(void) {
    int i, a[44], na, b[44], nb;

    scanf("%d", &na);
    for (i = 0; i < na; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    scanf("%d", &nb);
    for (i = 0; i < nb; i++)
        scanf("%d", &b[i]);
    if (is_subset(a, na, b, nb))
        printf("PODMNOZINA\n");
    else
        printf("NIE\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It appears to be dependent on whatever processes are running at the time.

Comment: It runs on an internet tester so it shouldn't really matter. (i failed to mention this, sorry).

Comment: `hashArray[hashKey(t[i])] != NULL`? How can `hashArray[hashKey(t[i])] == NULL` ? If `hashKey(t[i]) > ARR_SIZE` that's undefined behaviour, but `hashArray[hashKey(t[i])]` on most platform will return a non-meaningful integer anyway, not equal to NULL. I think you assume, that for any x: `0 <= hashKey(x) < ARR_SIZE`, that means that for any x: `hashArray[hashKey(t[i])] != NULL`.

Comment: `hashArray[hashKey(t[i])][j] == NULL` ? Why do you compare a pointer value with a integer value? Enable compile warnings and compare ints with ints. `hashArray[hashKey(t[i])][j] == 0`. NULL is usually defined as `((void*)0)`. Same with `return NULL;`.

Comment: The `if (hashArray[hashKey(s[i])][j+1] != NULL)` may access hashArray out of bound. On the last loop, when `j == ARR_SIZE - 1` and `i == ns - 1` and the first if is false, when `hashArray[hashKey(s[i])][j] != s[i]`, then `j + 1 = ARR_SIZE` so the `hashArray[...][j+1]` will access the `hashArray` out of bound.

Comment: `hashKey` function and in it's `while (data > ARR_SIZE) { data %= ARR_SIZE; }` is strange. It is just `if (data > ARR_SIZE) { data %= ARR_SIZE; }`, but really probably you meant `return data % ARR_SIZE;`. Can there be a and b integers, so that `a MOD b > b`? Secondly, `hashKey(ARR_SIZE)` will return ARR_SIZE, so all `hashArray[hashKey(s[i])]` may access `hashArray` out of bound, when `s[i] = ARR_SIZE`, then `hashKey(s[i])` will return ARR_SIZE, so it's `hashArray[ARR_SIZE]`.

Comment: @KamilCuk: All that code in the comments is hard to read. If you have so many things to tell, why don't you make it an answer?